# With a RESTful WCF service, trying to use WebFaultException to return error info, but the response is always empty

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, rest

Let's say my service is the following:

```
public class Clients
{
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedResponse, UriTemplate = "", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(MyClient))]
[FaultContract(typeof(MyFault))]
public string New(MyClient newClient)
{
  try
  {
    return Clients.NewClient(newClient);
  }
  catch (MyException ex)
  {
    throw new WebFaultException<MyFault>(new MyFault(ex.Message), System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    throw new WebFaultException<MyFault>(new MyFault(ex.Message), System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
  }
}
}
```

and the fault class is

```
[DataContract]
public class MyFault
{
  public MyFault(string data)
  {
    Data = data;
  }

  [DataMember]
  public string Data { get; set; }
}
```

Going by everything I've read about the WebFaultException, when the error handling block of code is hit, the response should have the status code I've set, and the body should be a JSON representation of the exception message. The status code part works; however, the response body is always empty (edit: by this I mean that when I call the service from my client side [in AngularJS], the response object consists of just the status code and a null Data field). I've also tried dispensing with the custom fault type and going with a WebFaultException`<string>`, but the results were the same. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You mention the response body is always empty. Can you detail what properties of the response you are looking at and how you are looking at it please.

Comment: @Wjdavis:When I call the service from my client side (in AngularJS), the response object consists of just the status code and a null Data field.

Comment: What happens if you change `WebFaultException<MyFault>(new MyFault(ex.Message), System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);` to `WebFaultException<string>(ex, System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);`

Comment: And if you debug the code running you can see the exception thrown and see the ex.Message value populated? Given your two catch blocks above you are also catching a custom Exception (MyException) so I cant be sure that the exception even has info in it.

Comment: There is indeed info in the MyException when it's thrown.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @NorbertNorbertson never did, sorry. Ended up wrapping the client object in a clientResponse object with a success indicator and status message.

Comment: thanks for the response @sarmatron. I think my case is due to WCF being set up as a Soap service but containing WebFaultException code. It's not ideal but it's not my code and for now I'll have to live with it.

Comment: I also have same issue...